# Scala's migrateDependencies tool says for3Use2_13 for a cross-compiled library

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm working on migrating a project from Scala2.13.12 to Scala3.3.1.  The project has several modules.  I'm using the [migration tools](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/scala3-migrate.html) discussed in the migration guide.

Running `migrateDependencies xplatformJVM`, I get:

```
[oat] $ migrateDependencies xplatformJVM
[info] 
[info] Starting migration of libraries and compiler plugins of project xplatformJVM
[info] 
[info] Valid dependencies:
[info] "com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.7.3"
[info] "com.lihaoyi" %% "fastparse" % "3.0.2"
[info] "com.lihaoyi" %% "scalatags" % "0.12.0"
[info] "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % "0.8.2" % Test
[info] "com.lihaoyi" %% "sourcecode" % "0.3.1"
[info] "com.lihaoyi" %% "fansi" % "0.4.0"
[warn] 
[warn] For Scala 3 use 2.13:
[warn] ("ca.uwaterloo" %% "oatlibxp" % "3.1.0-SNAPSHOT").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
[warn] ("ca.uwaterloo" %% "da_solver" % "0.3.1-SNAPSHOT").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
[info] 
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan. 29, 2024, 3:16:07 p.m.
[oat] $
```

The issue is that `oatlibxp` and `da_solver` are my libraries and I think they are cross-compiled for both Scala 2.13.x and 3.3.x.  Why am I getting the "For Scala 3 use 2.13" warning?  They were published locally.

```
bwbecker@bwbmac ca.uwaterloo % pwd
/Users/bwbecker/.ivy2/local/ca.uwaterloo
bwbecker@bwbmac ca.uwaterloo % ls -ld oatlibxp**/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxr-xr-x  7 bwbecker  staff   224B 29 Jan 15:15 oatlibxp_2.13/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxr-xr-x  7 bwbecker  staff   224B 29 Jan 15:15 oatlibxp_3/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxr-xr-x  7 bwbecker  staff   224B 29 Jan 15:15 oatlibxp_sjs1_2.13/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxr-xr-x  7 bwbecker  staff   224B 29 Jan 15:15 oatlibxp_sjs1_3/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
bwbecker@bwbmac ca.uwaterloo %
```

Comment: I would guess local repo is not checked. You'd have to publish the libs to a remote repo. Anyway, you can just change manually what the migration does